# Xamarin.Forms iOS - Blank White Launch Screen (Splash Screen)

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

On a Xamarin.Forms iOS project we started a couple years ago, we used to have a working launch screen. But recently I renamed and cleaned out a bunch of the images. Now the launch screen doesn't work, and no matter what I do, I can't get it to work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and I've tried creating a story board (LaunchScreen.storyboard), following the few crappy tutorials that are out there (like [this one](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/)), and I've verified that in info.plist, the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key with `LaunchScreen` string exist, and in LaunchScreen.storyboard (located in root of iOS project), it has a single view with a red background (`<color key="backgroundColor" colorSpace="calibratedRGB" red="0.92549019607843142" green="0.23529411764705882" blue="0.24313725490196078" alpha="1"/>`), and an image inside.

I've even tried a story board with just a red background and no image. No luck.

I've also tried just the Launch Image route, where I add a Launch Image Asset Catalog, I add images for the various resolutions, and in info.plist, in the Visual Assets tab, in the Launch Images section, I specify LaunchImage as the Source, and I leave the Launch Screen not set (as opposed to setting to LaunchScreen storyboard).

But no matter what I try - I ***always*** get a **blank white screen**. I've tried clearing the `obj` and `bin` folders in the iOS and PCL projects and restarting Visual Studio.

Why is this so difficult? What am I missing?

Comment: 1.Keep the `source` in Launch Images `none`  2.You said you rename and clear several images , try to remove the image in launchscreen , just have a red background and try again.

Comment: I've tried both with no luck.

Comment: I finally ended up fixing it, but I still don't know why it works now. Once I was able to get it to a point where it was showing the default load screen (with the ugly black grid, circles, and X on a white background - [like this](https://snag.gy/Rw2gor.jpg)) instead of the blank white screen, it was easy to create and modify a storyboard launch screen. My guess is it was some Xamarin or Visual Studio bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange issue, maybe related with iOS caching. Try to delete application from emulator/device then run app again.